# function to grab image urls out of text

Tags: javascript, regex, image, url

I am trying to write a simple javascript function to pull just img urls out of text.

i have nearly got it working but i am having a issue with params how can i remove them and also returning the full img url, could someone help not the best at regexs

```
document.write(getImagesInText("Whether the view should  hidden from (i.e., ignored by) the accessibility service. http://jsfiddle.net/ http://thickbox.net/images/plant4.jpg afhttp://thickbox.net/images/plant4.jpg?4t34t34t"));


function getImagesInText(text){

        var html = text;
        var urlRegex = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?)+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png)/gi;
        return html.replace(urlRegex, '<img src="$1" width="48" height="48"/>');

}
```

view the example here.
http://jsfiddle.net/7dJCm/1/

UPDATE

```
function getImagesInText( s ) {
    var html = s;
    var imgregex = /((http(s)?|ftp):\/\/[\S]*(\.jpg|.jpeg|\.gif|.png)[\S]*)/gi;
    var urlRegex = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?)/gi;

    html = html.replace(/(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.png)/gi, function( ext ) { return ext + " "; }); 

    html = html.replace(/(http|https)/gi, function( ext ) { return " " + ext; });

    html = html.replace(urlRegex, function( path ) {
           if(path.match(/jpg|png|gif|jpeg/g)){
             return "<img width='48' height='48' src='" + path + "' />";
           }else{
             return "<a href='" + path + "'>" + path + "</a>";
           }
    });

    return html;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7dJCm/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = "Whether the view should  hidden from (i.e., ignored by) the accessibility service. http://jsfiddle.net/ http://thickbox.net/images/plant4.jpg afhttp://thickbox.net/images/plant4.jpg?4t34t34t";

console.log( getImagesInText(s) ) // "Whether the view should  hidden from (i.e., ignored by) the accessibility service. http://jsfiddle.net/ <img src='http://thickbox.net/images/plant4.jpg' /> af<img src='http://thickbox.net/images/plant4.jpg?4t34t34t' />"

function getImagesInText( s ) {
    var regex = /((http(s)?|ftp):\/\/[\S]*(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.png)[\S]*)/gi;

    return s.replace(regex, function( path ) {
        return "<img src='" + path + "' />";
    });
}
```

Comment: hi null thanks for this just what i am after i have updated my answer i apologise in advance for the awful replace functions dropped in at the start but i needed a way to deal with if users just drop the url straight within the text so it doesnt break thanks

Comment: @user1503606 I can't understand why you'll need to do that replace? It's works if it's only an url. Btw. you can rewrite the replace to:

`s.replace(/(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.png)/gi, function( ext ) {
  return ext + " ";
})`

Comment: hi null you can see the problem i was having if you visit this link as a example http://jsfiddle.net/7dJCm/14/

Comment: @user1503606 ok i understand. But in that case I would treat it as an url and not a picture < imo.

Comment: ive updated the code think that should work solid for links and images thanks